# Combine arrays when they have similar element

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have 5 arrays inside an array,

`let arrays = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4], [4,5,6,7], [21, 34, 89], [555,  34]]`

Now, I want to group them if they have atleast 1 similar element.

Expected output.

`[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [21, 34, 89, 555]]`

Since array 1, 2 and 3 has similar element, they will combine. And array 4 and 5 has similar element so they will be combined as well.

```
var finalSimilarArray = [[String]]()

 let similararray = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [21, 34, 89, 555]]                   
 similarArray.forEach { array in
       similarArray.enumerated().forEach { index, array2 in
             if !Set(array2).intersection(Set(array)).isEmpty {
                  finalSimilarArray.append(contentsOf: [array] + [array2])
                  similarArray.remove(at: index)
             }
        }                        
 }
```

I tried to looping and conditions with no luck, not even close. to the real deal.

Thank you, I hope I explained it clearly. :D

Comment: Yeah I tried something but it's just a bunch of loops and conditions. And not even close to the real deal. :(

Comment: Should they come in a sequence to be grouped, what if your example has [7,8] at the end should it then be grouped with the first group or ignored?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson if you mean that what if there's another subarray [7,8] at the end. Then YES. it should be combine since 7 is also present in 3rd array.

Comment: I edited my question for clarification. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 2 cent: Start with a function which merges a single array into a list of (mutually disjoint) arrays:

```
func mergeOne<T>(array: [T], into merged: [[T]]) -> [[T]]
    where T: Hashable & Comparable
{
    var set = Set(array)
    var result = merged.compactMap { m -> [T]? in
        if set.isDisjoint(with: m) {
            return m
        } else {
            set.formUnion(m)
            return nil
        }
    }
    result.append(set.sorted()) // Or: result.append(Array(set))
    return result
}
```

The array is converted to a set so that overlapping tests with another array and joining the elements can be done efficiently. This requires the elements to conform to the `Hashable` protocol. The `Comparable` conformance is only needed to sort the merged arrays – if that is not needed then this constraint can be removed.

The above function compares the given array with each element of the list, and joins them if there is an overlap. The important point is to use the new enlarged array (actually: set) for the subsequent comparisons. So arrays with no overlap with the new array are kept in the list, and the others are joined to a new array which is then appended to the list.

With that utility function we can merge a given list of arrays easily:

```
func merge<T>(arrays: [[T]]) -> [[T]]
    where T: Hashable & Comparable
{
    return arrays.reduce(into: [], { $0 = mergeOne(array: $1, into: $0) })
}
```

Starting with an empty list, the array elements are merged repeatedly.

Examples:

```
print(merge(arrays: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [21, 34, 89], [555,  34]]))
// [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [21, 34, 89, 555]]
print(merge(arrays: [[1,2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [3, 5], [6, 2]]))
// [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Wow. This one worked, thank you @Martin R. You even made it generic. :D

Answer (score 1):

Compare each array element to every other array element to see if there is any overlap. If there is, then combine the arrays into a partial result. Next compare the partial result to each element in the results. If there is any overlap, then combine then. If not, then append the partial result to the array of results.

```
extension Collection where Element: Hashable {

    func unique() -> [Element] {
        return Array(Set(self))
    }
}

extension Collection where Element: Equatable {

    func containsAny(of other: Self) -> Bool {
        for element in other {
            if contains(element) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}

func merge(arrays: [[Int]]) -> [[Int]] {
    return arrays.reduce(into: Array<[Int]>(), { results, slice1 in
        var partial = slice1
        for slice2 in arrays {
            if slice2.containsAny(of: partial) {
                partial.append(contentsOf: slice2)
            }
        }
        if let index = results.firstIndex(where: { $0.containsAny(of: partial) }) {
            results[index] = (results[index] + partial).unique().sorted()
        } else {
            results.append(partial.unique().sorted())
        }
    })
}

print(merge(arrays: [[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4], [4,5,6,7], [21, 34, 89], [555,  34]]))
print(merge(arrays: [[1,2], [3, 4], [1, 3]]))
```

Results are:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [21, 34, 89, 555]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: This would not merge `[[1,2], [3, 4], [1, 3]]` into a single array.

Comment: @MartinR Good catch

Comment: Somewhat close but yeah Martin R 's comment is right.

Comment: It still does not merge `[[1,2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [3, 5], [6, 2]]` into a single array :)

Comment: Thank you for answering, but yeah still not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Set which guarantees unique values, when using .union which merges the values of two sets into one.

```
let givenArray: [Set<Int>] = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4], [4,5,6,7], [21, 34, 89], [555,  34]]
let expectedArray: [Set<Int>] = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [21, 34, 89, 555]]

let groupedArray: [Set<Int>] = givenArray.reduce([]) { (result, numbers) -> [Set<Int>] in
    var mutableResult = result
    if let indexOfNumbersToMergeWith = mutableResult.firstIndex(where: { (set) -> Bool in
        !set.isDisjoint(with: numbers) // Returns: `true` if the set has no elements in common with `other`
    }) {
        mutableResult[indexOfNumbersToMergeWith] = mutableResult[indexOfNumbersToMergeWith].union(numbers)
    } else {
        mutableResult.append(numbers)
    }

    return mutableResult
}

print(groupedArray == expectedArray) // prints: true
```

EDIT:

I've updated the answer to support the following given array `[[1,2], [3,4], [1,3]]`

```
let givenArray: [Set<Int>] = [[1,2], [3,4], [1,3]]
let expectedArray: [Set<Int>] = [[1,2,3,4]]

let groupedArray: [Set<Int>] = givenArray.reduce([]) { (result, numbers) -> [Set<Int>] in
    var mutableResult = result

    let indexesOfNumbersToMergeWith: [Int] = mutableResult.enumerated().reduce([], { (result, arguments) -> [Int] in
        var mutableResult = result
        let (index, numbersToCompare) = arguments

        // Returns: `true` if the set has no elements in common with `other`
        if !numbersToCompare.isDisjoint(with: numbers) {
            mutableResult.append(index)
        }
        return mutableResult
    })

    if !indexesOfNumbersToMergeWith.isEmpty {
        // Note that I've sorted the indexes in descending order. This is because everytime you remove an element, the indexes of the elements beyond is reduce by one.
        let numbersToMergeWith = indexesOfNumbersToMergeWith.sorted(by: { $1 < $0 }).map { (index) -> Set<Int> in
            return mutableResult.remove(at: index) // removes and returns number set
        }
        mutableResult.append(numbersToMergeWith.reduce(into: numbers, { $0 = $0.union($1) }))
    } else {
        mutableResult.append(numbers)
    }
    return mutableResult
}

print(groupedArray == expectedArray) // prints: true
```

Comment: Doesn't work for this sequence: `[[1,2], [3, 4], [1, 3]]`

Comment: @RobertCrabtree I've made changes to the snippet.